# How can I move compilation albums into a "Various Artists" folder?

Tags: music, rename

Currently my music is sorted like this:

```
Music
├── Artist 1
│   ├── Album 1
│   └── Album 2
├── Artist 2
│   ├── Album 3
│   ├── Album 4
│   └── Album 5
├── Artist 3
│   └── Album 5
├── Artist 4
│   └── Album 5
└── Artist 5
    └── Album 5
```

What is the easiest way to reorganize it like this?

```
Music
├── Artist 1
│   ├── Album 1
│   └── Album 2
├── Artist 2
│   ├── Album 3
│   └── Album 4
└── Various Artists
    └── Album 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to download an application onto your computer, then I would advise installing Picard. Follow these steps:

1. Install Picard using:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install picard
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo aptitude install picard
   ```
2. Once it's installed successfully, open the application (the full name is MusicBrainz Picard).
3. Go to *Options* → *Options...* A new options window will pop u.
4. Select *File Naming* on the left hand side. Once selected, you will be able to pick the file naming scheme that you want for normal albums or albums with various artists on it.

The picture below shows the final result if you decide to use this application:

[image: Picard Options]

If you want more information about how Picard works, please look over the help documentation found here: [Picard Documentation](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Picard_Documentation)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This solution sounds promising, but I don't think it's general enough. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that Picard is only usable on albums which happen to be included in the MusicBrainz database. Surely not by coincidence, those albums in my collection which fall exception to this requirement are precisely those which need reorganizing.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the album to be in the musicbrainz.org to have this work. The site helps make it easier if it is on their database but you can edit them without looking at their DB. I do that when I can't find albums that I know exist. Still takes some manual work to complete but will save them just the same.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of attaining this would be to individually sort them into order.

You could start by going into Nautilus and pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> which would give you a split screen.

Then on one part of the split screen you would create a `Various Artists` folder and select the music then move it into the folder that you created.

Clearly this is a time consuming process, especially if you have a large music library.

Hopefully someone will be able to give you an answer which will automate what you want faster.

[image: Nautilus]